# Normal map tangent without subdivision

Tags: normals, subdivision-surface, normal-map

When i apply a normal map tangent, i need to subdivide the mesh for the effect to happen. When i apply a normal map object, the map takes effect without subdivisions. How do i not have to subdivide the mesh and the normal map tangent have effect?

Comment: Did you use google translate?

Comment: Yes, but did you understand? I can explain it differently.

Comment: I am not sure. You probably talk about tangent-space normal map vs. object-space normal map, but you don't need to subdivide for both to work. If the normal map was correctly baked, there is no need to subdivide to smooth the mesh. I think you need to post pictures of the mesh and the normal map, maybe even share the .blend file.